# Can python behave handle assertRaises

Tags: python, python-behave

I'm starting to use **Behave** to implement some tests.  I would like to replace some of my existing unittest (which are more feature tests).  Some of these uses assertRaises to check that certain calls to the back-end service raise the errors they should.  Is it possible to have something similar in Behave (or maybe rather Gherkin)?

The following unittest calls my backend service and as a guest has logged on, is not able to perform the admin task (do_admin_task).  It should raise an exception.

```
def test_mycall(self):
    service = myservice('guest', 'pwd')
    self.assertRaises(NoPermission, service.do_admin_task, some_param)
```

In my feature file, how would I create my scenario?  Like this?

```
scenario: test guest can't do an admin task
   given I log on to my service as guest / pwd
    when I try to perform my admin task
    then it should fail saying NoPermission
```

I believe that this will already raise an exception in the **when** step, so won't even get to the **then** step.

One potential way I could imagine around this is to create a specific step that performs both of these steps and does the exception handling.  If I however want to mock errors in lower level calls, then I would have to re-write many of these steps, which is exactly what I'm hoping to avoid by switching to Behave in the first place.

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When thinking on the Gherkin level, the exception is an expected outcome of the *when* step. So the step definition should have a try block and store the result/exception in the context. The *then* step can check this result/exception then.

```
@When(u'I try to perform my admin task')
def step_impl(context):
  try:
    context.admintaskresult = myservice(context.user, context.pass)
    context.admintaskexception = None
  except Exception as ex:
    context.admintaskresult = None
    context.admintaskexception = ex

@Then(u'it should fail saying NoPermission')
def step_impl(context):
    assert isinstance(context.admintaskexception, NoPermissionException)
```